# Angular 2 lazy load modules using aot and different pipeline

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, jit, angular2-aot, aot

I am working in a big app and we want to have lazyload modules in order to improve the performance, but we want to use AOT (performance) and at the same time we want to keep separate pipelines in order to deploy only the module changed if there is no any dependency with other one. We are working in several team focused in different modules.

After investigating a lot, I don't find any way to do it. Have anyone had the same issue?

Everything works with JIT, having different javascript files in separate pipelines and we have tried to compile everything in only one build process in AOT and works, but we couldn't do AOT and different pipeline at the same time.

Comment: We have exactly the same scenario. Options we have considered include deploying the bundled files from the lazy module build, but without the hashes - this potentially breaks caching an outdated version of the bundles. But it always seems to come back to rebuilding/bundling the entire app.